# How to Install libunity-dev in Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian

I am trying to compile Telegram Desktop project according to [this](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/master/QTCREATOR.md) guide. I need to install `libunity-dev` package but it's not available in the repository of Debian Jessie. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package is from the **experimental** distribution. That means it is likely unstable or buggy.

To install `libunity-dev` edit `sources.list` :

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add the line

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian experimental main
```

Save: `ctrl + O`

Confirm: press `Enter`

Exit: `ctrl + x`

Update your package

Dependencies: `libdbusmenu-glib-dev`,`libdee-dev`,`libgee-dev`,`libglib2.0-dev`,`libunity-protocol-private0` and `libunity9`

Type the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install libunity-dev
```

To get more informations, please visit `https://packages.debian.org/experimental/libunity-dev`

Comment: Is the source code available for this library? I am unable to find it. I don't want to add experimental to my `sources.list`

Comment: @Barracuda, see https://code.launchpad.net/libunity for the library's source code.